# Didn't get Excavator badge from editing 6 month old post

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I recently made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6430236) edit to a post that was older than 6 months, but didn't get the excavator badge. Is this a bug, or do you only get it from editing answers? I assumed 'post' meant a question as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There was a bug that prevented awarding when the post owner was deleted - note you can't get the badge for your own posts, so we weren't properly accounting for null owners in this check.

A fix has been pushed and you now have the badge.

Comment: Just curious, how many badges were awarded as result of the bug fix, network wide?

Comment: Not sure about network-wide, but on Stack Overflow, it was 441 new awards.

Comment: Network-wide (including SO) looks to be around 1000!

Comment: wow you should totally get a badge for this! ;)

Comment: Or get paid for every bug you fix - that always works out great... for the dev :)