# Excavator badge description confusing

Tags: feature-request, badges

The [Excavator badge description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1287/excavator) states:

> Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months.

However it seems that there is an extra criterion required to have it awarded - that you can not own the edited post, see: [Didn't get Excavator badge from editing 6 month old post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278881/didnt-get-excavator-badge-from-editing-6-month-old-post).

Can the description be changed to indicate this? Presumably it will also affect the Archaeologist badge too.

Comment: I think many of the badge descriptions omit some technical details in preference of brevity.

Comment: Apparently, the edit must also be accepted by that person as far as I know.
Also: does `first post` correlate to `one post` or the specific first post of a person or in a queue?