# Apparently I've edited 1 >6-months-inactive for the Archaeologist badge but not got Excavator?

Tags: bug, edits, badges

On my "user" page on SO, I'm seeing that I have 1/100 for Archaeologist, the description says:

> Edit 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months

But I have not yet been awarded Excavator, whose description says:

> Edit first post that was inactive for 6 months

Unless my reading comprehension is lacking, this looks like a bug? Could it be related to this bug: [Didn't get Excavator badge from editing 6 month old post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278881/didnt-get-excavator-badge-from-editing-6-month-old-post)?

Comment: Blame caching?  Check back in a few hours to see if you've earned the badge.

Comment: How long ago was this?  Badges do take some time to apply.

Comment: I first noted the inconsistency at least 12, possibly 18 or 24 hours ago (I didn't make a note). I left it till now exactly because I suspected caching!

Comment: The criteria for the badges are somewhat vague. It could be that suggested edits do not count?

Comment: Also, your [only potentially qualifying edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8084411/revisions) was applied only 11 hours ago (05:15 UTC). That's still within the 'blame caching' time window in my book.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it counts suggested edit.
 I got it on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/badges/119/excavator?userid=356789) on this [suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/349969), so I would (as always) blame, caching.

Comment: Not really caching. The script that awards badges runs on a schedule. You need to give it at least 24 hours. Some badges are lower priority than others.